# Clang rejects std::array initialisation but gcc accepts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, user-defined-literals

I am learning about user defined literals and I wrote the following program that works with gcc and msvc but clang rejects it. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j7WG8ha6s)

```
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
struct Literal
{
    std::array<char, N> arr;
    constexpr Literal(char const(&pp)[N]): arr(""){} 
};
 
template<Literal> 
constexpr auto operator""_S()
{
    return 4;
}
int main() {
    auto i = "test"_S;   
    auto j =  "ch"_S;       
}
```

I want to know which compiler is correct here. The error on clang says:

```
<source>:7:48: error: initializer-string for char array is too long, array size is 3 but initializer has size 5 (including the null terminating character)
    7 |     constexpr Literal(char const(&pp)[N]): arr(""){}
      |    
      <source>:17:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'Literal<3>::Literal' requested here
   17 |     auto j =  "ch"_S;
```

Comment: It seems like a compiler bug, perhaps related to caching of template instantiations. I say this because removing the declaration of `i` fixes `j`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Note that the program compiles if both string literal have the same length. For example `auto i = "test"_S;   auto j =  "chjt"_S;`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kcz3rco33)

Comment: @user12002570 - Yes I noted the tag, hence I posted a comment, and not an answer. That was another observation to through into the mix.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, this does seem to be a bug to me too. I'll report it shortly and then post the bug report as answer perhaps.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Btw just changing the order of declarations of `i` and `j` makes the program compile. Definitely a compiler bug. Like `auto j = "ch"_S; auto i = "test"_S;` compiles.

Answer (score 8):

This is a [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/82167). Note that just changing the order of declaration of `i` and `j` makes clang accept the program.

Here is the relevant bug report:

[Clang rejects valid program involving user defined literal](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/82167)